# Amazon Linux 2023 Blocking Outbound Connections

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, amazon-linux-2023

So I've been working with EC2 instances in two separate contexts. In the first context I simply am building an AMI for some spot instances. In the other context I have an EKS cluster with node groups.

One day everything just stopped working. I looked into it and it has to do with outbound requests from the instances. I could use `ping google.com` but not `curl google.com` for example. I created many different instances in different availability zones, different sizes, and different distros but all with the exact same network settings.

The takeaway is that Amazon Linux 2 poses no issues for outbound requests but Amazon Linux 2023 does. Are there known causes for this? Notable that this coincided relatively with the release of (more so with my update to) AMI release version 1.27.4-20230825.

Finally, how can I fix this in my EKS cluster. I don't really have a way to change distros so ideally there would be an easy workaround.

Comment: Are you sure that the distro upgrade is the only different factor here? Have yo you tested with 2 identical EC2 instances with the same security group, in the same VPC etc. but with only the distro different?

Comment: Can you post the output of `curl -v www.google.com` ?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Yes. Two completely identical instances (t2.micro) operating in a public subnet in AZ-1 in us-east-2. Side by side compared all networking settings. But Amazon 2023 worked as recently as last week. They've dropped a new default AMI though for Amazon Linux 2023.

Comment: @Philippe I'm not at my computer at the moment but first it will reject the ipv6 request, the ipv4 request to port 80 on googles server is attempted, then it says "Could not connect to server" or something similar.